# WP_Query taking 3-4 seconds to execute, optimizations suggestions?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I started managing a new Wordpress website and I've noticed that some queries are taking about 3-4 seconds to execute. I am using Query Monitor plugin to check this.

Anyone with more experience in Wordpress WP_Query could help me with optimizations tips?

```
new WP_Query(array( 'no_found_rows' => TRUE, 'category__and'=> 
array($rozeCategoryID, $aktualeCategoryID), 'posts_per_page' => 9,
'meta_key' => 'nmb-pozicioni-rubrike', 
'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'modified' => 'DESC' ) ));
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Onj2.png) is the function that I have.

P.S The amount of posts is around 130,000.

Answer (score 0):

Given the number of posts you have (and the number of comparisons that have to be run), I don't know how much faster you'll be able to get it just by optimising the query, short of upgrading your server.

If you want to increase the speed of the page I'd consider trying to cache the results (or the first page of thrm) using the transient API. You could then clear the transient on publish_post.

There's a guide to setting this up on https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-transients-in-wordpress which looks to go through it pretty nicely.